# Delphi - Generating files from Program Files folder Win7

Tags: delphi, windows-7

recently I encountered a file-creation problem, when my delphi application is executed using a start-menu or desktop shortcut, even if its ran as admin. If I run it directly from its folder as admin, there are no issues.

Basically I have created a delphi 32-bit GUI program which builds an SFX archives using zipforge archiver. If I run program from e.g. C:\myProgramFolder, application runs normally and builds archive to the specified output folder, however, when I run it using shortcuts, I'm getting I/O 105. I guess it should be problem which has something to do with Win7 security policies, but there's maybe somebody who ever dealt with this kind of problem, so I would be very thankful for any advice.

This is a procedure, which causes I/O 105:

quickfix.ini is a file which is used to give the SFX stub a display information, that's why it is there

```
procedure TfrmMain.Buildinstaller1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  presentPath: string;
begin
  presentPath := ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName);
  SynEdit1.Lines.SaveToFile(presentPath + '\quickfix.ini');
  CopyFile(pchar(presentPath + '\quickfix.ini'),
      pchar(edSourcePath.Text + '\quickfix.ini'), false);
  CopyFile(pchar(presentPath + '\bin\Uninstall.exe'),
      pchar(edSourcePath.Text + '\Uninstall.exe'), false);
  DeleteFile(presentPath + '\quickfix.ini');
  if (edSourcePath.Text <> '') and (edOutPutPath.Text <> '') then begin
    saveExe.InitialDir := edOutPutPath.Text;
    if saveExe.Execute() then begin
      frmProgress.Show;
      try
        // this is a line where the problem begins
        with archiver do begin
          TempDir := GetTempDirectory;
          FileName := saveExe.FileName;
          OpenArchive(fmCreate);
          BaseDir := edSourcePath.Text;
          AddFiles('*.*');
          CloseArchive();
        end;
      except
        on E: Exception do begin
          writeln('Exception: ', E.Message);
          Readln;
          frmProgress.ProgressBar1.Position := 0;
          frmProgress.Close;
        end;
      end;
    end;
    MessageDlg('QuickFix install successfully built!', mtInformation,
        [mbOk], 0);
    frmProgress.Close;
  end else begin
    MessageDlg('Source and/or output path not set. Please review.',
        mtInformation, [mbOk], 0);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: GUI or console application? 32 or 64-bit? How are you "building an SFX archive" (from scratch, from 3rd party code)? What type of file I/O (old Pascal, TStream, etc.)? What is the destination folder you're trying to write to? There's insufficient information here to use to answer the question; you're asking about a vaguely described problem.

Comment: 32-bit gui, using zipforge to build the sfx. Another thing is, if I run my app directly from containing folder as an admin, there's no problem, but if I run it as admin using desktop shortcut, it won't let me create it. I'm completely stuck....

Comment: Then you're writing somewhere within Program Files,which is not allowed in most cases under Windows Vista and higher. Fix your code so it's not doing so. (I/O error 105 is *File not open for writing*, which according to the documentation is caused by using Write/WriteLn without an open console window.)

Comment: Update: it turns out that the problem is not program-files related. There is something more spooky. I have updated my question, please check it out.

Comment: I elevated application rights to admin. When I run application locally, everything works. When I start it by shortcut from the start menu, I get I/O 105 again. Any suggestions???

Comment: Sorry. You've accepted an answer here, which indicates you've found a solution. I have no suggestions.

Comment: I already said that you haven't supplied enough detail for anyone to give you a detailed answer. You accepted an answer which indicates your problem is solved. Very unlikely that anyone will pay more attention to this. I tried to help you, and guide you towards a better question, and so to an answer. You rejected that. This is the inevitable outcome. I'm still prepared to help if you cooperate.

Comment: David, I really try. I accepted solution, because it was one of the reasons as Zipforge had Tempfolder set to Exe path. I changed it, but another trouble came out. According to my former question it did not solve the problem itself. I'm a newbie to stackoverflow, so I try to describe my deal as far as I can. The system is very easy: My program creates an exe file in a desired directory. I recoded my app with admin privileges elevation. Seemed it WILL solve the problem, but it did not. This situation seems absolutely ridiculous to me. Locally it works, launched by shortcut it does not.

Comment: I don't think we can do much more without more details. A repro would be a start. You should do some debugging too and gather information.

Comment: If you can point me to the details you would like to know, I will supply them. For the moment I don't know what other details can I give you. I've got no previous experiences describing my problems on stackoverflow. Sorry.

Comment: A complete program (cut down) and instructions on how to reproduce the behaviour. And diagnostics from your debugging.

Comment: I did. I will be thankful if you see something. Debugger does not fetch anything, because the problem is related to the shortcut-execution. When ran from IDE, or locally, there's no trouble. Tks.

Comment: This is exactly what David said. You shouldn't be writing temporary files into the program files folder.  Are you aware of the existence of other places on your hard disk other than program files folder that might be a better place for you to write your files? Microsoft doesn't want you to do what you're doing. Stop it.

Comment: You are writing to the program files directory like I said.

Comment: Your bigger problem is, you are not indenting your code.

Comment: My problem is not writing to program files and I do not see one line saying I'm doing it except of ini files, but even when I start it from program files, my function works. Unless I execute my app using shortcut in start menu.

Comment: Sertac Akyuz - applause for effort you put on focusing of my real problem. Just to let you know, I'm a newbie here and when posting my code for 1st or 2nd time, I've deleted all indents here. Hope you will sleep better now ;)

Comment: @Lukas - You don't need to put any effort to make your code harder for us to read. It is just unnecessary.

Comment: I absolutely understand your point and I agree, but I ask you: please tolerate and apologize my stackoverflow knowledge level. Thanks for update.

Comment: Tolerate what? Mocking in a comment about being pointed your *real* problem and seeing the point in another? You don't need my toleration, good luck with your programming.

Comment: @Sertac - Sorry. You started mocking about no part of a subject first, ignoring a fact it could be a mistake. Over.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I strongly recomend you check your AntiVirus logs to see if your application wasn't perhaps being blocked by your AntiVirus software.

Also I would recomend you check Windows Event Logs to see if your application wasn't perhaps being blocked by Windows DEP (Data Execution Prevention).

In both cases the most likely cause for this would be the fact that your program that isn't digitally signed is generating an executable file and could therefore be detected as potentionally dangerous application.

BTW is your progarm perhaps also creating some temporary file during its execution? And if it is is that file perhaps being stored in your application folder?

**EDIT:** Based on new information you claim that your program works OK when being run directly but fail when being run from shortcut. I strongly suggest you check the shorcuts WorkingDirectoy paramter.

Also you should avoid adding path delimiters "\" manually becouse your path might already contain one. So instead make use of IncludeTrailinPathDelimiter method which automatically checks if delimiter is already there and adds it if it is not.

So instead of:

```
SynEdit1.Lines.SaveToFile(presentPath + '\quickfix.ini');
```

you should use

```
SynEdit1.Lines.SaveToFile(IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter(presentPath) + 'quickfix.ini');
```

Comment: @Lukas Syn Durjan I'm glad my answer was helpfull to you, but since I pointed out multiple reasons it would be nice if you can leave a comment which specific reason whas the cause for others to know.

Comment: Your answer helped me to think further, I found out that my zipforge archiver was using my local exe path as its TempDir. This was one of the problems, but now I found out another. I made a lots of mistakes trying to describe my issue and looks like I was really not sure what's going on myself as well. Sorry.

Comment: SilverWarrior, you're genius. It was my working directory parameter of my shortcut. 10000x thanks!

Comment: and especially thanks for focusing on what I have problem with instead of useless critique on the way I express my problem or how I miss indents, which are my real problem. I appreciate your help!

Comment: So now that you know that the working directory is affecting your aplication go and find the code that it is depending on it. Becouse only this way will you compleetly fix your problem especially since it is posible to change working directoy for specific application at any time even from external applications.

Comment: As far as me trying to focus on problem I'm more understanding on the fact that most begginers don't even have suficient knowledge to propely ask question. I know this becouse about 7 years ago I was in same position. Another thing is that I always try to think out of the box which can be quite helpfull sometimes. But I also understand many other pepole here on SO which doesen't take so much time for figuring an answer than me becouse they already psend hours programming and working on their own stuff in their jobs. But for me programming is still more like a hobby but I hope this will change.

Comment: @Silver You still didn't explain why the location of the executable changed the program's behaviour. It's not at all clear to me that anyone here understands anything at all. FWIW, ExtractFilePath  **always** includes a trailing path sep.

Comment: I just rebuilt my function, I completely forgot to include working directory so I've put it in as an additional parameter and it's okay now. And why it affects its behavior.....that's the question....

Comment: There's no answer here. You don't appear to want to learn. You seem more concerned about saving face. You are alienating multiple people who could teach you and help you learn.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Based on the latest edit I belive OP already solved the isue of revieveing I/O error when his application was executed from a folder which was withing Program Files folder structure. Now he is expiriencing problem when launching his program through shorcut becouse it seems that his program relies on using of working directory but I don't know which part of his program since he hasn't posted all of his code and the part he did dodesent seems to relly on workig directory at all. That is why I wrote to him that he must find the part of code that rely on this and fix it.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan As far as using of IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter method goes. From my expirience I have learned that it is good practice to use this all the time becouse some API cals don't always return paths with trailig delimiter so you either need to be verry carefull or try to figure out why your application is failing in certain circumstances. So it is safer to use this everywhere even when it is not realy necessary.

Comment: According to the accept, it's either the av or the double path sep that leads to exe location influencing behaviour. So be it.

Comment: Yes, IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter is sensible practice. TPath.Combine is better still. My comment was in response to your quote "because your path might already contain one". Simply remove the word "might" since there can be no doubt.

Comment: @LukasSynDurjan I'm not sure why is working directory affecting your prgoram so much becouse based on your posted code youd don't use it anywhere. But it is posible that your archiving component does. So it might not be bad for you to studdy the components documnetation in more depth or check their forums to see if someone already had similar problem of working directory causing I/O errors.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Looking back at comments the OP said that his archiver component used the Executable location as its defult TempDirectory which was causing the errors in the beginning.

Comment: Nobody has a clue anymore what this is all about.

Comment: @SilverWarior - the shortcuts were created using installer before. Basically, I have an interface to build up config ini file which is included within the sfx package. After executing the package, this config is extracted to get the app details (installshield-like approach). I used this extractor also for my ini-file builder, which is even creating an output, that's the connection between shortcuts and deploying an sfx.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - I already agreed, that the form of my problem was incorrect. I came in with an exact problem and afterwards I rewrote the topic. I did not ask what particular functions perform, it's not about saving face, nor about learning. I had an issue, which I could not move out from (maybe because a lot of time spent in front of screen) and all I got was one guy talking about learning, one guy talking about indents and one who thought exactly about my question, who finally pointed me the right way. Don't understand why should I be the worst.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - just to make things clear, I came to pascal over C++ more than 12 years ago and sometimes I come to a ridiculous situation and I've seen that on SO I can find very funded and corrent answers, that's why I'm disappointed of approach of some of you (two to be exact) and this was not what I've expected. The reactions are possibly related to my registration date, but whatever...these snippets do not come from a Delphi tutorial book....thanks anyway.

Comment: So the location of the executable changed behaviour for why exactly? Those double path seps did that did they?

Comment: nope, I have tried both configurations, deleimiters appear to work even when used twice, the parameter which affects this behavior is Starting Directory of shortcut - for sure - tested. If the startdir is not set, I come to an file not op. for output. Really do not understand why, I still keep looking for additional info about how it can affect, but I did not come to any conclusion. The most funny thing is, that it does not have any problems writing to local dir (maybe because filetype - .ini), but has problems with specified output. Even if ran elevated.

Comment: @LukasSynDurjan I recomend you do next things to narow down your problem even further. Fist before you use any path informration make sure to store it in its variable and pass that variable to the function instead. This will help you find out any posible problems with double or missing delimiters. Next try checking to see if there is any differnece if the output filder has spaces in it or not. This can be quite common problem when using external utilities through command inteface as they could treat space as end of command and any text after the space as parameter to that command.

Comment: Also check to see if destination folder might contain any unicode character which my not be supported in paths of your archiving component. Same might goes for path size. If it has more than certain number of characters it might simply get turncated and thus result in nonexisint path. And finally you could go and download Process Monitor (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896645.aspx) which can be invaluable in tracking problem with file access as it show what files are tried to be accesed even when this fails due to unknown path or file lock.

Answer (score 6):

Since Vista, released 10 years ago, with UAC enabled, even admin users run with restricted rights by default. Only when running a process elevated does the user token for that process get admin rights.

The program files folders have security settings that mean that standard user cannot write to them. You need to save your files to a folder other than the program files folder. The application data folder is one obvious choice.

If this general answer does not fully explain your problem then please provide a complete program that demonstrates your scenario precisely.

Comment: Thanks for answer, David, I'm not writing to Program Files, I'm only running my program from Program Files and that probably restricts its functionality to write anywhere. As previously said, if I run it from C: there is no problem writing to any folder on the disk (even Program Files).

Comment: I very much doubt that. You might not realise you are writing to the folder that contains the executable, but the evidence suggests otherwise. Now, please read your question again and ask yourself how anyone is going to give a more specific answer than mine.  To get the best out of Stack Overflow, you have to put effort into asking good questions.  With all the necessary detail.  And once you are able to do that you'll find that you won't need to ask so many questions because your improved attention to detail will allow you to solve your problems yourself.